# Changing the sign near author email

Tags: symbols, footnotes, authblk

I use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\date{\today}
\title{Some Title}
\author[1]{Prof. First Person\thanks{PFh@som.ac.il}}
\author[2]{Dr. Second Man \thanks{SMh@elsac.il}}
\affil[1,2]{Department of Important People, Latex University}
```

I would like to replace the sign of little cross near the second author to something else or alternatively to use only the numbers also near the emails. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `symbols` are actually footnote markers, so `fnsymbol` comes into action. An easy way to change this is using `footmisc` and define another set of `fnsymbols` with `\DefineFNsymbolsTM{somename}`.

Please note that the syntax of this command is a list of macro name pairs, i.e. a text symbol and the 'corresponding' command in math mode.

I just added some symbols and shuffled the order of some symbols in `otherfnsymbols`.

After definition, the symbols must be activated with `\setfnsymbol{otherfnsymbols}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}

\DefineFNsymbolsTM{otherfnsymbols}{%
  \textbullet \circ
  \textsection   \mathsection
  \textdagger    \dagger
  \textdaggerdbl \ddagger
  \textasteriskcentered *
  \textbardbl    \|%
  \textparagraph \mathparagraph
}%

\setfnsymbol{otherfnsymbols}


\date{\today}
\title{Some Title}
\author[1]{Prof. First Person\thanks{PFh@som.ac.il}}
\author[2]{Dr. Second Man\thanks{SMh@elsac.il}}
\affil[1,2]{Department of Important People, Latex University}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]